# Regex for match followed by one or more words?

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

```
--Return rows that have one or more words that follow a string that
--begins with 'Call me Ishmael.'


with string_row as
( select 'Call me Ishmael.'                as line_1 from dual union all     --False
  select 'Call me Ishmael. Some years ago   .' as line_1 from dual union all --True
  select 'Call me Ishmael  Some years ago   .' as line_1 from dual union all --True
  select 'Call me Ishmael,  Some years ago   .' as line_1 from dual union all --True
  select 'Call me Ishmael .'                 as line_1 from dual union all    --False
  select 'Twas the best of times. Some years ago.' as line_1 from dual union all --False
  select 'Call me Ishmael     '             as line_1 from dual  -- False
)  
select line_1
        from string_row where 
        regexp_like(line_1,'Call me Ishmael\w{1,}')  --original attempt.
        regexp_like(line_1,'Call me Ishmael[., ]+\b([\w .,]+)') --Attempt that appears to work on Javasrcipt.
```

Questions:

Why does this regex not work?

What regex does work?

Comment: I've been having difficulty posting lengthy questions lately. So I'm having to piecemeal it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197468/where-can-i-get-more-information-about-my-submission-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex works:

```
Call me Ishmael[., ]+\b([\w .,]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zyPQ2v-G1PlwCbKb)

The text after `Call me Ishmael` *and* any periods, commas, or spaces that follow it, is put into capture group one.

The problem with your regex, `Call me Ishmael\w{1,}`

Is that it is trying to match one or more (`{1,}`, which is equivalent to `+`) of any letter, digit, or underscore (`\w`). Many of your lines contain commas, spaces, and periods, so it needs to be expanded to capture those character as well.

---

It seems that [*Oracle regex*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) does not have word-boundaries. So try this instead:

```
Call me Ishmael[., ]+(\w[\w .,]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N4no150AHvBCwHnx)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't want to match the first row because it doesn't have any words after Ishmael. I want a match only if there are additional words after Ishmael.

Comment: I've changed it so it matches starting at the first word boundary *after* any spaces, commas, or periods.

Comment: I see that this works on your demo and this is what I want. However, this does not appear to be working on Oracle 11g using regexp_like.

Comment: I don't have an Oracle setup at the moment, so I'm in a bad position here, but I did notice from [their documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) that word boundaries are not acceptable. I've updated my answer. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, that works on Oracle11g using regexp_like. Thanks, this is what I need.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help. *Surprised* I could help, to be honest.

Comment: You were a big help. I'm grateful for your assistance and time. Thanks